# Object with null properties by QBean mapping on left joining table / Querydsl

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm using Querydsl 4.1.0 to generate my Qtable from database, and also by myself, create the Qbean for transforming result into my Java object. The problem I'm facing is, my A class has a B class property , and if I use ' A left join B', then if there's no existed B for A's id in database (which will result in null values of those columns from B table on that row), my A object after transformation will have a B object, with all null properties. Is there anyway to avoid this undesired B object to be instantiated?

I can see that the problem here is `newInstance()` method of QBean always create a B instance and return it regardless of the fact all field's values is null, which is not so right in my opinion.

---

My classes :

```
protected final  QBean<Contact> contactQBean = 
                    Projection.fields(Contact.class,
                    qContact.id, qContact.firstName, qContact.lastName, 
                    qContact.middleName, addressQBean.as("primaryAddress"));
```

### ------------------------

```
 public class Contact {
private Integer id;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private Address primaryAddress;
```

My query :

```
Map<Integer, Contact> resultMap = queryFactory.from(qContact)

            .leftJoin(qContact.contactAddressFK, qAddress)

            .transform(groupBy(qContact.id).as(contactQBean));
```

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow! Add a minimal code example to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is too difficult and complex. I do not know the answer. But maybe you can try to go to your IDE and copy some other codes from stack.
Hope it helps